# How to create a dynamic color list with SASS?

Tags: css, sass

I want to create a custom color list with SASS.

```
$color-list: cyan blue;
$cyan-codes: #B2EBF2, #80DEEA, #4DD0E1, #26C6DA, #00BCD4, #00ACC1;
$blue-codes: #B2EBF2, #80DEEA, #4DD0E1, #26C6DA, #00BCD4, #00ACC1;

@for $i from 1 through 6 {
@each $color in $color-list {
.color-#{$color}-#{$i*100} {
  color: nth(AAA, $i);
}
}
}
```

Everyting is OK except the `color: nth(AAA, $i);` part. What should I use instead of AAA to point each color-codes list. It's working if I use `color: nth($cyan-codes, $i);` but I want to create a dynamic usage to point $cyan-codes, $blue-codes ... etc.

The CSS output is like that:

```
.color-cyan-100 {
  color: #B2EBF2;
}

.color-blue-100 {
  color: #B2EBF2;
}

.color-cyan-200 {
  color: #80DEEA;
}

.color-blue-200 {
  color: #80DEEA;
}
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use variable interpolation to call a variable, sadly. Your best bet is to use [SASS maps](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/deep-getset-maps/). Here is a little example of what you could do:

```
$my-colours: ( // Define your colour map
   'cyan': (#B2EBF2, #80DEEA, #4DD0E1, #26C6DA, #00BCD4, #00ACC1),
   'blue': (#B2EBF2, #80DEEA, #4DD0E1, #26C6DA, #00BCD4, #00ACC1)
);

@each $map in $my-colours {
    $name: nth($map, 1); // Returns the name of the map
    $map: map-get($my-colours, $name); // Returns a sub-map
    $i: 0; // For your class naming

    @each $colour in $map {
        $i: $i+1; // Increase the iteration value

        .color-#{$name}-#{$i*100} {
            color: $colour;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It's what I wanted. Just one correction, i should be start from 0, not 1.

Comment: Glad I could help. I ran into the same issue recently. And yes, `$i: 0;`, my bad.

Answer (score 3):

[jaKhris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3624336/jakhris)'s answer is good, but you could simplify it a bit and not have to keep track of the iteration. Here's a [sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/20a5465c857af6b50f10cc5f7e57ccd9)

```
$my-colours: (
   'cyan': (#B2EBF2 #80DEEA #4DD0E1 #26C6DA #00BCD4 #00ACC1),
   'blue': (#B2EBF2 #80DEEA #4DD0E1 #26C6DA #00BCD4 #00ACC1)
);

@each $map in $my-colours {
    $name: nth($map, 1);
    $list: map-get($my-colours, $name);

    @for $i from 1 through length($list) {
        .color-#{$name}-#{$i}00 {
          color: nth($list, $i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is simpler. :) Thanks for your answer.